# Is Realm's .where faster than filtering a list manually?

Tags: filtering, realm

I am creating a project using a realm database.

I also have a lot of lists which I wish to filter while the user types.

The biggest one of them will probably be the list of customers

Currently I am using realm by using a wrapper class for each object (if anyone has a better suggestion I'm definitely open to it)

The objects I am using are like this:

```
public class Customer_Realm extends RealmObject{
    private int _id;
    private String _name; //...etc

    public int get_id(){ return _id; }
    public void set_id(int id) { _id = id;}
    //etc
}


Public class Customer() {
    Customer_Realm _base;
    public Customer(Customer_Realm base) { _base = base;}
    public int get_id(){ return _base.get_id(); }
    public void set_id(int id) { _base.set_id(id);}
    //...etc
}
```

Along with this I have an ArrayListAdapter for customer objects. My question is, would this:

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends ArrayListAdapter<Customer> {
   List<Customer> _customers;
   String _filter = null;

   public void set_filter(string name) {
      _filter = name;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   @override 
   public int getCount(){
      return get_visible().count();
   }

   public Customer getItem(int position){
      return get_visible().get(position);
   }

   public List<Customer> get_visible() {
      if (_filter == null)
         return _customers;
      List<Customer> visible = new ArrayList<Customer> ();
      foreach (Customer c : _customers){
         if (c.get_name().contains(_filter)
            visible.add(c);
      }
      return visible;
   }
}
```

Or would this be better?

```
public class CustomerAdapter extends ArrayListAdapter<Customer> {
   Realm _database;
   String _filter = null;

   public void set_filter(string name) {
      _filter = name;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   @override 
   public int getCount(){
      return get_visible().count();
   }

   public Customer getItem(int position){
      return get_visible().get(position);
   }

   public List<Customer> get_visible() {
      RealmResults<Customer_Realm> result = null;
      if (_filter == null)
         result = _database.allObjects(Customer_Realm.class);
      else
         result = _database.where(Customer_realm.class).contains("_name",_filter);

      List<Customer> visible = new ArrayList<Customer> ();
      foreach (Customer_Realm c : result){
         visible.add(new Customer(c));
      }
      return visible;
   }
}
```

Unfortunately my database contains only a small sample of data(and realm for windows does not have an editor so I can enter data manually) so  when I try either implementation I do not see any difference, I was wondering if anyone has any experience with what happens when you use such an implementation with a large number of data

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Normally using Realm query would be much faster than filtering manually since Realm query is written in native code and has been optimized a lot. But you are copying result to another list which is not necessary at all slows down the whole method a lot. Another benefit of using the `RealmResults` than your manual list is `RealmResults` will be updated when you db changs, no need to re-run the query again.

Comment: yeah, I guess I could use the actual RealmObject as the list item, and wrap it when the user clicks on one of them to use my methods, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try doing what you said